longtable too much blank space
i'm using longtable  but i got too much space ,
I don't want that , I don't want any space between rows


\begin{longtable}{|p{6cm}|p{8cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cas d’utilisation }  & S’inscrire   \\
\hline
\textbf{Acteur} &Utilisateur  \\
\hline
 \textbf{Pré-condition} &Système en marche 

Adresse e-mail et mot de passe sont validés\\
\hline
\textbf{Post-Condition} & Compte créé \\
\hline
\textbf{Description du Scénario Principal} & \begin{itemize}  \item Le système affiche l’interface de l’inscription.
\item Les acteurs saisirent ses coordonnées personnelles.
\item Les acteurs cliquent sur le bouton « S’inscrire ».
\item Le système vérifie les données.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\item Le système affiche un message de la réussite de
l’inscription.
\end{itemize}
  \\
\hline
\textbf{Scénario d'Exception} & \begin{itemize}  \item Informations invalides.
\item Compte existant.
\item  hello hello
\item  hi hi hi hi
\item  zy
\end{itemize}
  \\
\hline
\end{longtable}


Your whole itemize environment is a single table row. And longtable can only break table rows to the next page, but not parts of table rows.

what i must do ?

Break the itemize in, e.g., single items per table row.

BTW: itemize usually does not number and therefore I'm not able to make your example compile. Please always show a minimal working example that can be used to reproduce the problem.

i removeed the itemsize bu i still have the same problem https://prnt.sc/-wQ_wffgbz6K

Then do, what I've told you in my third comment. Sorry, but usually we need to be able to reproduce the problem, to be able to help. And note, that a screenshot is not a minimal working example and cannot replace it.

@d3ridi You still have all the text in the same table row. Page breaks are only between table rows.

For all users (no close immediately the question because he is a new user). Thank you.

It would appear that you've modified the default line-spacing (possibly by modifying \linespread or \baselineskip) somewhere in your document; however, you haven't provided any information about the specifics of this modification. Please provide more detailed information.
